# Is there a word that refers to both a speaker and a writer?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, writing

I'm writing an essay and I'm comparing a speaker's work to a writers work. My transition is "Edwards was not the only (insert word) that spread his Puritan beliefs in his works. Anne Bradstreet illustrates the Puritans' plainness..." At the moment I have "literary figure" written, but I'm wondering if there is a better word for it.

Comment: Christians generally refer to a person who pronounces a sermon to a congregation as a "preacher", not a "lector"; a "lector" is usually the person who reads the Biblical verses appointed for the occasion.

Comment: @StoneyB ok, but do you have a word that refers to both a speaker and writer is what I am asking.

Comment: Is the word "apologist" applicable to Puritans?  ("[Apologist](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/apologist)" has a technical meaning of "a person who writes or speaks in [defense] of a belief, a cause, or a person's life.")

Comment: Were both of these people "[evangelists](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/evangelist)"?

Comment: You could use [*proponent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proponent) - it means, loosely "someone who argues for or advocates something".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edwards was not the only **proselytizer** that spread his Puritan beliefs through his works.

> One who seeks to convert people to his or her beliefs.

Perhaps writings is better than works...Just a thought.

Comment: "Works" has an awkward (unintended) double meaning in this sentence.  Besides meaning "things you say or write", it also means "all the things you do or achieve".  The Puritans were heavily influenced by Calvinism.  Calvinism opposed the Catholic idea that "good works" could help a person achieve "salvation".

Comment: *Works* should be avoided, for the reason given by @Jasper; but *writings* excludes Edwards' speech to auditors, which seems to contradict what OP is looking for. How about 'words'?

Comment: They were probably sermons, then.